# sql server 2005 view the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am create a job within a sql server agent. I want to view the result. Not just whether it worked or not but what happened.

For example if my step command was select * from table1. I want to see each row and column of the table. Where is this stored or how do I see the results?

Thanks.

Bob Avallone

Comment: do you mean you wish to step through like with a debugger? or do you mean that it should be stored in some logging location for later review?

Comment: What is the point of having a background job execute a SELECT query?

Comment: Aaron makes a very good point.  If you want to see information along the way, how do you want to do it?  Messages are in the SQL Agent log.  You can email yourself information.  You can store it in a table for future reference.

Comment: Select query was just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Under Steps, Edit Step, Advanced, Output Files; create an output file.

Thanks for the responses.

Bob